# Trouble scraping sports table - python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm having a lot of trouble scraping results off a sporting table in Python.
I am new to scrapping and have tried everything I can find online.
The website is https://www.nrl.com/stats/teams/?competition=111&season=2022&stat=38
and I'm just trying to get the team name and tries.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far in your **scraping** code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have the good requirements:
   if you are using `Anaconda` go to Anaconda cmd line and type:

```
> pip install beautifulsoup4
> pip install requests
```

2. Now, You can try a scrapping library called `beautifulsoup`, you can specify the name of the `div` you want in the html source code of your website, with your link and the library catch all the data, example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#create variable page
page = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7286456/criticreviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt')
#create the variable soup and calling BeatifulSoup library for our web page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
file = open("data.txt", "w") #don't forget create a data.txt file in the same repository of your file.py
#maping the div with class_="summary" with the function find_all()
for x in soup.find_all('div', class_='summary'):
    print(x) #print the data scrapped 
    file.write(x.text) #store the data in the file.txt
    file.write("\n")  
file.close()
```

More details in my Scrapping project https://github.com/mehdimaaref7/Scrapping-Sentiment-Analysis/blob/master/big_data.py

The `data.txt` file is optional, you can just use the variable `x` with `print(x)`, to display the data you need to scrap.

Comment: Looks like there is a json inside the requests response, you can also extract the data from

```j = json.loads(soup.find('div', {'id':'vue-stats-detail'}).attrs['q-data'])```
and iterate through it to extract all the team names

```print(', '.join([t['teamNickName'] for t in j['totalStats']['leaders']]))```

Comment: Yes Thank you  Nacho, I think this is exactly what the student needed, with my example he can probably extract now the data from his website without any problem. Let us know if you have done what you want! good day stack Community ;)

Comment: Thank you very much guys, worked a treat! Much appreciated

Comment: Nice, Hope we helped you :) ! Have you used `json.loads()` function ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate. Just get the json then let pandas parse it into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.nrl.com/stats/teams/?competition=111&season=2022&stat=38'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('div', {'id':'vue-stats-detail'})['q-data']
jsonData = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['totalStats']['leaders'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
    teamNickName  ... played
0          Storm  ...     24
1       Roosters  ...     24
2      Rabbitohs  ...     24
3       Panthers  ...     24
4           Eels  ...     24
5        Cowboys  ...     24
6         Sharks  ...     24
7        Broncos  ...     24
8     Sea Eagles  ...     24
9        Raiders  ...     24
10        Titans  ...     24
11       Dragons  ...     24
12       Knights  ...     24
13      Warriors  ...     24
14      Bulldogs  ...     24
15  Wests Tigers  ...     24

[16 rows x 5 columns]
```