# How to get data from a pop up using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[image: Url of this image is "https://software.cisco.com/download/home/283970225/type/282088134/release/11.5(4)"]

So what I am trying to do with this web page is to get all the details such as Release Date, FileNmae for all the green links like the one shown in the picture(The data shown for the first green link can only be seen if you hover over the green link). But I am having trouble with data extraction, from the pop up.

Link of the web page:
https://software.cisco.com/download/home/283970225/type/282088134/release/11.5(4)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find your answer here [Trouble scrapping sports table - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940954/trouble-scrapping-sports-table-python/71941194#71941194)
You need to use a python library called `beautifulsoup`. Hope this help you !